# how do I perform the following function for a given list, using python

Tags: python, list

for any given list I need output as shown below

```
l1 = [2,3,4]

output  = [2*3+ 3*4 + 4*2] = [26]

similarly 

l2 = [3,4,5,7,8,3]

output = [3*4 + 4*5 + 5*7 + 7*8 + 8*3 + 3*3] = [156]
```

The length of the list is dynamic and so could go up to 100, and the code needs to dynamically do the calculations based on the length of the list.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: What would be the result for a list with only one element?

Comment: that would be the number itself

Comment: you can use the zip function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotate the list by appending the first element to a slice of everything after the first element; then `zip` the original list with the rotated list.  Use `sum` to generate the actual numeric sum, and `str.join` with f-strings to generate the rest of the output.

```
>>> def rot_sum(nums):
...     rot_nums = list(zip(nums, nums[1:] + [nums[0]]))
...     return f"[{' + '.join(f'{a}*{b}' for a, b in rot_nums)}] = [{sum(a * b for a, b in rot_nums)}]"
...
>>> rot_sum([2, 3, 4])
'[2*3 + 3*4 + 4*2] = [26]'
>>> rot_sum([3,4,5,7,8,3])
'[3*4 + 4*5 + 5*7 + 7*8 + 8*3 + 3*3] = [156]'
```

Comment: perfect! that was must useful although I will have to add a condition that if its a single number its returns a single number! but the rest looks fine!